# When cross-compiling gstreamer on Linux using meson --cross-file, iconv dependencies are lost

Tags: gstreamer, cross-compiling, meson-build

I specified my own gcc toolchain in the meson cross-file

[image]

Error screenshot:
[image: Error screenshot]

Error Message:

```
glib| Run-time dependency iconv found: NO (tried builtin and system)

subprojects/glib-2.74.1/meson.build:2051:13: ERROR: Dependency "iconv" not found, tried builtin and system
```

[Meson.build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuI6m.png)

I tried to add the following properties to the my-cross-file.txt file

```
[properties]
c_link_args = ['-L/path/to']
cpp_link_args = ['-L/path/to']
```

The dependency library path is correct, but it is still invalid.

Comment: The dependency detection uses pkg-config.  You may need to set `pkg_config_libdir` in the under properties so meson knows where to find the `pkgconfig` directory.